# child pid XXXX exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in HTTPD_PATH

Tags: php, apache, centos7

I'm working with a business solution that is chipped with PHP and apache.

I want to browse the documentation of this solution but I get this error:

```
[notice] child pid 8514 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /home/myuser/dc/docsyssrv/httpd
```

I have `Apache/1.3.34 (Unix) PHP/4.2.3` chipped with the solution.

I'm on `centos 7.7`

**PS**: the solution is tested under RedHat 7.6.

Comment: i updated the LD_LIBRARY_PATH for some reason in my .bash_profile. When i comment the line theproblem was solved.